# What does 'array' method in RACSequence (ReactiveCocoa) do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

This is a code snippet from Ray Wenderich's [iOS 7 Best Practices article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/55386/ios-7-best-practices-part-2). He's basically fetching a JSON file and making a model for each in the list;

```
return [[self fetchJSONFromURL:url] map:^id(NSDictionary *json) {
                RACSequence *list = [json[@"list"] rac_sequence];

                return [[list map:^(NSDictionary *item) {
                    return [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[WXDailyForecase class] fromJSONDictionary:item error:nil];
                }] array];
    }];
```

What does that `array` do?

Comment: It evaluates the `RACSequence` and returns an `NSArray` with the objects (think of it as the `NSEnumerator`'s `-allObjects`)

Comment: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/ReactiveCocoa/2.3.1/Classes/RACSequence.html#//api/name/array

Answer (score 0):

`RACSequence`'s instance method `map` returns another `RACSequence` instance. So if you want a `NSArray` instance, you have to use the `-[RACSequence array]` method to evaluate the entire sequence and convert its values into an `NSArray`.

By the way, the `map` method is executed lazily; as the sequence produces values, you will receive them one by one until you unsubscribe or reach the end of the sequence. But calling the `-array` method will block the current thread if all of the values are not yet available (until they all become available, at which point the method will un-block and return the array).

Comment: Thank @erikprice to fix my English.